# Firebase function works locally but returns "error":"MODULE_NOT_FOUND" when calling server deployed version

Tags: node.js, firebase, yarnpkg

I am getting a `"error":"MODULE_NOT_FOUND"` status message when I call a deployed Firebase function through a GET request. The function works just fine locally with `firebase emulators:start`, so why the dissonance between the deployed and local versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you properly install the node module that seems to be not found using `npm install --save` WITHIN the `/functions` folder and not `yarn add`. When calling `firebase deploy`, the firebase CLI currently relies on pushing up node modules installed through npm, not yarn.

Comment: `yarn add` saves to package.json - and firebase uses does not depend on which package manager you are using. yarn should work just fine.

Comment: You're right. I think the important thing is to be `cd`'d within the `/functions` folder at time of packaged add